# Not sure how to deal with with large blocks of text with expect script

Tags: linux, expect

I'm trying to write an expect script to automate the WowzaStreamingEngine installer. Running the installer outputs a long (some might say absurdly long) EULA, which then requires some interactions - accepting the EULA, setting a username and a password, repeating the password, and setting whether or not it's supposed to start at boot. I've recorded my steps with autoexpect, but I have a couple of problems. First, it will only run in the same terminal that I ran autoscript in (I'm assuming it because autoexpect recorded a specific amount of lines each time I pressed the space bar to advance the script past the absurdly long EULA), but the script won't complete - it gets to the last question, and just hangs. Here is the full, unmodified script (interaction, space bar excepted, begins at line 1284):

http://pastebin.com/uWk7vyZW

I've tried cutting all the blocks of text out, reducing the script to the point where only the questions that require interaction are included:

http://pastebin.com/dsUqQ0WX

but that doesn't move past the first block of text in the EULA.

The closest I've come to get the script to complete, was cutting out everything that came after the last interactive prompt (I posted a 3rd link, but I need more reputation points to post 3 links).

That seems to get me back to a user prompt, but it's non functional - I have to cntl-c to get to a functional user prompt.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here's the third link: http://pastebin.com/5ZRgnnQn

Comment: Look at whether `expect` can handle **heredoc** type blocks of information. Your options are either redirecting the EULA with process substitution (i.e. `< <( <EULA.txt )` or feeding expect with a **heredoc** or possibly a **herestring**. (a quick search on both will disclose the syntax). I don't use expect, so you will have to check its ability to handle redirected input, but those are the mechanisms that make most sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar answer to Dinesh's but you don't need to spawn a shell, so it's even simpler:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout -1
spawn sudo ./WowzaStreamingEngine-4.1.2.deb.bin

expect {
    -gl "*--More--*" { send -- " "; exp_continue }
    -ex "Do you agree to the above license terms?"
}
send -- "yes\r"
expect -gl "*User Name: "
send -- "UserName\r"
expect -gl "*Password: "
send -- "password\r"
expect -gl "*Confirm Password: "
send -- "password\r"
expect -gl "*Please enter a Wowza Streaming Engine license key*"
send -- "license key\r"
expect -ex "Start Wowza Streaming Engine automatically when this system reboots?"
send -- "yes\r"

expect eof
```

Trimming an autoexpect-generated script can be a bit of an art.

Comment: This comes maddeningly close to working, but then it gets to the final prompt, which is not in your script, so I added: 

    expect -gl "*Start Wowza Streaming Engine automatically when this system reboots? \[yes or no\] \r"
    send -- "yes\r"

But it just hangs, and does not pass the final "yes" through to the script. Any thoughts on why?

Comment: Simply because I missed that from your autoexpect. I'll update my answer.

Comment: You have to be careful with square brackets inside double quotes: square brackets are Tcl's syntax for command substitution (much like the shell's backticks). Make sure you escape them with backslashes. I actually removed them from the patterns in my answer.

Comment: Awesome, that worked perfectly! I'm looking up the flags right now - they're not laid out in the man page the way most man pages do. Thanks so much, @glenn!

Comment: Expect is an extension of Tcl, so you'll want to start with http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm

Answer (score 2):

With `exp_continue`, all your needs will be satisfied in short. It will cause the `expect` to run again. Using this, we can simplify the script as follows,

```
set timeout 300; # Setting 'timeout' to 5 mins
set prompt "#|>|\\\$"; # We escaped the `$` symbol with backslash to match literal '$'
set linuxPassword "yourpassword"
spawn /bin/bash; # spawning 'bash' shell here
expect -re $prompt
send "sudo sh WowzaStreamingEngine-4.1.2.deb.bin\r"
expect {
        "password for $tcl_platform(user): $"  {send "$linuxPassword\r"; exp_continue}
        -- "--More--" {send " "; exp_continue}
        "\\\[yes or no]" {send "yes\r"; exp_continue}
        "User Name: $" {send "username\r"; exp_continue} 
        "Password: $" {send "password\r"; exp_continue} 
        "enter a Wowza Streaming Engine license key" {send "license-key-here\r"; exp_continue}
        -re $prompt {puts "INSTALLATION COMPLETED SUCCESSFULLY"}
        timeout {puts "TIMEOUT HAPPENED"}
}
```

`$` symbol and `[` are important to both `Tcl` and `Expect` which is why it is escaped with backslash simple. `\\\$` will match literal `$`, similarly, `\\\[` will match literal `[`

Here, we have to be careful on the timeout. I have set it to 5 mins and within that interval all our required patterns should be matched. Else, timeout will happen for sure. You can change the `timeout` as per your requirement.

**Note :** I have tried to check this installation in my pc where I stuck at the 'User Name' part. After giving username, it is throwing error as

```
A password is required. Please try again.
WowzaStreamingEngine-4.1.2.deb.bin: 1242: read: Illegal option -s
```

Due to this I'm not able to validate my code till the end. So, check and let me know for changes.

Comment: Don't put comments where you put them! Expect will consider the words to be "pattern action" pairs!

Comment: "illegal option -s" -- do you have an old version of bash? `help read` shows `-s  do not echo input coming from a terminal`

Comment: @glennjackman : Thanks for notifying me. I have updated the answer. By the way, I am using  bash version `4.2.25` . Ubuntu LTS12.01. I thought this error is due to the installation bin file which I am running. Also, as the user 'standard_deviation' mentions to get the prompt, I thought he may need to interact with the `bash` which is why I have spawned `bash`